# How to add form inputs class names in array in jQuery

Tags: jquery

How can I add the classes in the form below in an array with jQuery? The jQuery function searches data in the database but when I complete the first input the following are automatically filled with the same data as the first input because they have the same class.

```
function search(val) {
  $(".search-box").val(val);
  $(".suggesstion-box").hide();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="frmSearch">
  <input type="text" class="search-box[]" placeholder="Search" />
  <input type="text" class="search-box[]" placeholder="Search" />
  <input type="text" class="search-box[]" placeholder="Search" />
  <input type="text" class="search-box[]" placeholder="Search" />
  <div class="suggesstion-box"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

I need each input to be filled in with the data entered in each input.

Thank you!

Comment: The question is confusing.  You talk about classes, then you talk about an array, then you talk about the data entered.  What is it you want exactly? Show the HTML you will start with, and the result (array, whatever) that you want to end up with.

Comment: Thank you. I reformulated the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

`document. getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;`

This will return an array of elements that you can access.

For jQuery:

```
$("input").each(function() {
  $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: Corrected for both ways

Comment: It doesn't, it's an example and he may use it as he wants.

Comment: Thank you for help but didn't work. I reformulated the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but this solution does not work. I will reformulate my problem: I have 4 inputs that behave like search boxes. when entering text in the input field, the Ajax script searches for product codes in the database, which can be selected from the dropdown menu.

[product code input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l19CQ.jpg)

but when I select the code from the dropdown menu, all inputs are self-complete with the same product code because they have the same class.

[all inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5K1or.jpg)

I need to select another product code per each row.

My code is:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('keyup', '.input_cod', function(){
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "search_code.php",
    data:'keyword='+$(this).val(),
    beforeSend: function(){
      $(".input_cod").css("background","#FFF url(../images/LoaderIcon.gif) no-repeat 165px");
    },
    success: function(data){
      $("#suggesstion-box").show();
      $("#suggesstion-box").html(data);
      $(".input_cod").css("background","#FFF");
    }
    });
  });
});

function cauta(val) {
  $(".input_cod").val(val);
  $("#suggesstion-box").hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <td style="width:120px;"><input type="text" name="cod[]" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Cauta cod" class="input_cod"></td><div id="suggesstion-box"></div>
  <td style="width:120px;"><input type="text" name="cod[]" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Cauta cod" class="input_cod"></td><div id="suggesstion-box"></div>
  <td style="width:120px;"><input type="text" name="cod[]" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Cauta cod" class="input_cod"></td><div id="suggesstion-box"></div>
  <td style="width:120px;"><input type="text" name="cod[]" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Cauta cod" class="input_cod"></td><div id="suggesstion-box"></div>
</table>
```